# How do you publish for direct download in Visual Studio Marketplace

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I have created a Visual Studio Extension and published it on Visual Studio Marketplace.

I have specified a link to my website, instead of uploading the file to the Microsoft Site.

The extension is visible from within Visual Studio, but when you click on download it opens a browser to download the extension, rather than downloading it directly in Visual Studio (as is common for other extensions).

Is this behavior because I specified a link, rather than uploading the installation file?

If not, what would cause this behavior? I have not found any documentation of this detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this behavior because I specified a link, rather than uploading the
>   installation file?

I think so, if you upload the extension(.vsix) with `Uploaded extension` option, it will behave like normal situation.(VS will download it directly.)

But if you use `Provide a link` option, when you click the download button in VS, it will call browser to download the `xx.vsix` instead of downloading it in VS IDE.

For the extension uploaded with **installation file**(most extensions are uploaded in this way), the download button in VS marketplace is **Download**.

[image]

And for the extensions uploaded with **link**, the button here is **Get Started**. Such as [OzCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CodeValueLtd.OzCode), [DevExpress .Net Application Framework](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DevExpress.DevExpressNETApplicationFramework)...

I published two extensions with different ways(installation file and link), when I
 click download button in VS, the A(uploaded with xx.vsix) will be downloaded directly and B(uploaded with link) will be downloaded by browser. So I think what you experienced is expected behavior for VS extension manager.

Comment: Thanks Lance, I have marked this as the answer (I don't doubt that it is correct) although I have not been able to upload my VSIX yet. I can actually upload the file, but when I finally click on "Save & Upload" to commit the change, I get the error **Upload failed: TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: de0185ef-c3fa-488c-a072-e83614c4929d.** I think I should report that to Microsoft.

Comment: I am now over that hurdle. I build a new version with a higher build version (and some other very minor changes) and was able to upload it. The download in Visual Studio now works (although it seems to have a problem with the progress bar).

Comment: It seems that you now upload it with installation file, so you're downloading it directly in VS and see the progress bar, if you meet something strange with the progress bar you can share it here, I guess maybe I can report this issue :)